# Constructor Properties (private) with getter and setter

Tags: typescript

Assume we have this class with one property:

```
class iPhone {
    private _year: number;

    public constructor (year: number) {
        this._year = year;
    }

    get year(): number {
        return this._year;
    }
    set year(value: number) {
        this._year = value;
    }
}
```

And i want to use with this constructor in other syntax:

```
class iPhone {
    public constructor (private year: number) {
    }

    // Getters and setters ????
}
```

My question is this: with the second syntax, it is not possible to use a private variable and make get and set?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is this, with the second syntax it is not possible to use a private variable and make get and set ?

Your code does use a private variable. The problem you probably ran into is that that private variable is called `year`, and then it sounds like you tried to create a public accessor called `year` as well. You can't have two properties with the same name.

You could use a different name, as you did in your first example:

```
constructor(private _year: number)
```

...but both the parameter name and the property name will have the `_`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECWAKALA9gOwKbQN4FgBQ0h0ADgK4BGIsw0waEALgE6nAPJMAUxTsAbmAaYA+gE90YJtABc0VKQC25dEwCU2fEWgBffJqIBzdA2jjJnVbPlKVGglqJNjpJqmgNEsCADoxEpgDc+oS69oQQxqb+nAIgpOhWispqdg5EHl6+ZlIAvNCx8UFhOvihQA)

---

Side note: The type must be the same in the getter as it is in the setter. You have `number` and `boolean` in your question, which won't work.